# Using SVGS in blazor page

Tags: razor, blazor

I have a razor component and I want to add an SVG to it.

Would It be best to create a component for each SVG so that I can re-use it pretty easily or would it be better to just include the SVG into the blazor page?

Those are just the two ways I thought that it could be done, whats the best way to go about this and how can I implement it?

Haven't found any rescources, so I wasn't able to try anything.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I gave it  try,  as far as I can see the Blazor Component model works perfectly well with Svg:

> SvgHolder.razor

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
   @ChildContent
</svg>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

}
```

> SvgSample.razor

```
<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />

@code {

}
```

> TestPage.razor

```
<SvgHolder >
    <SvgSample />
</SvgHolder>
```

Comment: Very good idea.. though since im using mostly paths, I will skip the SvgSample and just stuff some loops in there

Comment: Try to change fill and size from testpage.razor now? it will not work.

Comment: @jerryurenaa - I can do that without any problem.

Comment: @HenkHolterman do you mind sharing? I'm learning it.

Comment: Ask a separate question. Comments don't count on this site.

Answer (score 4):

One way that I found to do it:

Add the files inside wwwroot:

[image: wwwroot example]

then just add it to the HTML page:

```
<img src="Images/scissors.svg" />
```

EDIT:
This works if you don't need to edit the image with css.
Read @J-Ho comments.

Comment: It works, but if you do it this way it is treated as img-element.
You can't style img-elements the way you could svg-elements. svg-elements are commonly used for icons, which have hover and all other effects applied to them. You can for example change svg-elements fill and stroke color with css, but not if it's static img-element.

Comment: @J-ho, I didn't know that. Thank you for this explanation.

Comment: Also note that Chrome caches these image files very aggressively.  You'll need a cache-busting scheme if you do it this way.

Answer (score 3):

I would let the HTML do the heavy lifting. We can do this by using the [`<svg>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg), [`<defs>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/defs), and [`<use>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use) HTML tags.

**Step 1:** Set up an SVG definition Library using the `<svg>` and `<defs>` tags.

The MDN doc linked above for `<defs>` states:

> The <defs> element is used to store graphical objects that will be used at a later time. Objects created inside a <defs> element are not rendered directly.

I will be placing my SVG definition Library in the index.html file because that is where we put Google fonts, CSS libraries & stylesheets, the Blazor loading animation, the reload error message, and the Framework script.

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <svg class="loading-progress">
      <circle r="40%" cx="50%" cy="50%" />
      <circle r="40%" cx="50%" cy="50%" />
    </svg>
    <div class="loading-progress-text"> </div>
  </div>

  <div id="blazor-error-ui">
    An unhandled error has occurred.
    <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
    <a class="dismiss"></a>
  </div>

  <!-- here -->
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none">
    <defs>
      <circle id="circle-test" cx="5" cy="5" r="4"/>
      <path id="calendar-icon" d="M7.5 8C7.75 8 8 8.25 8 8.5V11.5C8 11.7812 7.75 12 7.5 12H4.5C4.21875 12 4 11.7812 4 11.5V8.5C4 8.25 4.21875 8 4.5 8H7.5ZM5 0C5.40625 0 5.75 0.34375 5.75 0.75V2H10.25V0.75C10.25 0.34375 10.5625 0 11 0C11.4062 0 11.75 0.34375 11.75 0.75V2H13C14.0938 2 15 2.90625 15 4V14C15 15.125 14.0938 16 13 16H3C1.875 16 1 15.125 1 14V4C1 2.90625 1.875 2 3 2H4.25V0.75C4.25 0.34375 4.5625 0 5 0ZM13.5 6H2.5V14C2.5 14.2812 2.71875 14.5 3 14.5H13C13.25 14.5 13.5 14.2812 13.5 14V6Z" />
    </defs>
  </svg>
  <!-- here -->

  <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
</body>
```

**Note:** Make sure each SVG tag has an `id` attribute with a name.

**Note:** If a single SVG icon requires multiple SVG tags, make sure that the `id` attribute is on the parent. This can be accomplished using [`<g>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g), like so:

`<g id="parent-name"> ... child SVG tags ... </g>`

However, in the example above, I am using two single-line SVG icons.
I plan to come back in the future to add this to the example code above.

---

**Step 2:** Add the `<svg>` and `<use>` tags wherever you want to display your SVG.

```html
@* Component.razor *@
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none">
  <use href="#circle-test" fill="red"/>
</svg>

@* Component2.razor *@
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none">
  <use href="#calendar-icon" fill="blue"/>
</svg>

@* Component3.razor *@
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="36" height="16" viewBox="0 0 36 16" fill="none">
  <use href="#calendar-icon" fill="black"/>
  <use href="#calendar-icon" x="20" fill="red" stroke="black"/>
</svg>
```

**Notice** that I gave my SVG `href="#circle-test"` element a `fill` color and between the three different `href="#calendar-icon"` SVGs, I modified the `fill` color, `stroke` color, and the `x` attribute. I can directly change any attribute dynamically that wasn't defined in the definition from the SVG definition Library that we created in Step 1.

**WARNING** make sure you are using `href` inside the `<use>` tag and not `xlink:href`. `xlink:href` is deprecated.

---

**Step 3 [Optional]:** Use CSS to style your SVGs

If you want to add `:hover` effects or create a style using a CSS class so that you don't have to write out each attribute for each SVG. Create a CSS class and apply it to the corresponding `<use>` tags.

```css
.primary {
  fill: blue;
}

.primary:hover {
  fill: red;
  stroke: orange;
}
```

```html
@* Component4.razor *@
<svg viewBox="0 0 30 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <use class="primary" href="#circle-test" stroke="red"/>
  <use class="primary" href="#circle-test" x="10" />
</svg>
```

This will set both SVGs of `href="#circle-test"` to be filled with the color blue. The first circle has the attribute `stroke` set to red, so it will have a red stroke, while the second circle won't have a stroke. When either circle is hovered over its `fill` will change to red and add a `stroke` of orange (or change the `stroke` to orange).

**Note:** If I put `stroke: "green"` in the `.primary` CSS style then it will give both SVGs the green stroke, this is important to note because now you can't override the stroke by using the `stroke` attribute in the HTML. So even though `<use class="primary" href="#circle-test" stroke="red"/>` defines the `stroke="red"` it doesn't matter, it will use `class="primary"` and use a green stroke. However, you can override this with in-line CSS.
Like this: `<use class="primary" style="stroke:red" href="#circle-test" />`

**Note:** Don't style the SVG by its `id` attribute (In my example I don't want to style `#circle-test` or `#calendar-icon`, instead I create a `.primary` class). This is related to what I said in Step 2, "I can directly change any attribute dynamically that wasn't defined in the definition from the SVG definition Library". This holds true for using CSS, the `id` attribute is defined in the SVG definition Library, so if we style that id in CSS then that becomes part of the SVG definition and can't be changed.

As far as I know, there isn't a way to create a default style that can be overridden by the `<use>` tag for an SVG, because of this you will always have to use attributes or a CSS class to style the `<use>` tag

Answer (score 1):

> Since Blazor renders HTML, browser-supported images, including Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) images (.svg), are supported via the  tag:

```
<img alt="Example image" src="image.svg" />
```

source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#scalable-vector-graphics-svg-images